# How to fix NPM high severity vulnerabilities? (Pollution)

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, lodash, npm-update

i wanted to install some npm packages but i get the same error always

"3 high severity vulnerabilities"

when i press npm audit fix

i get always this:

[image: this is the error i get with every command i use]

i tried updating lodash and  jsdoctypeparser since the links say that pollution problems come with old versions of lodash and jsdoctypeparser but it doesn't work (at least the command to run the update, it gives the same error)

also tried the npm audit fix --force but it's the same

Answer (score 0):

If you can't update jsdoctypeparser then you're stuck. The real question is, can you update jsdoctypeparser without breaking your package? You don't need to update it to the current version (9), you just need to upgrade it past 2.0.0-alpha-5 (although the more up to date you can get it the better).